# How to export results obtained by "Display" in GAP to a .txt file

Tags: gap-system

I started to use GAP for computing table of characters for symmetric groups. I would like to export the result of the following

```
Display(CharacterTable(SymmetricGroup(4)));
```

into a .txt file (which later on I would like to import to Mathematica). My first guess was to use

```
PrintTo("file1",Display(CharacterTable(SymmetricGroup(4))));
```

but it does not work. How to do it properly?

Comment: I suggest to generate Mathematica input from GAP, instead of trying to parse GAP output from Mathematica. E.g. `List(Irr(CharacterTable(SymmetricGroup(4))),ValuesOfClassFunction);` will give the matrix of character values which you can then print (perhaps with some minimal code written) in format which Mathematica can process. You can also access other information, e.g. class names if you need them.